# "References to generic type JsonResponse should be parameterized"

Tags: java, generics, servlets

I have a Servlet for handling Ajax requests which gives response in JSON-format.

I get this warning on line as commented below. Type safety: The method setResponseData(Object) belongs to the raw type JsonResponse. References to generic type JsonResponse should be parameterized

Should I be doing this another way, or is it safe to add SuppressWarning annotation

```
public class JsonResponse<T>
{
    private T responseData;
    private boolean success;
    private String errorMessage;
    // + Getters and Setters
}

public class AjaxJson extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        String function = request.getParameter("func");
        if (function == null)
            function = "";

        JsonResponse<?> jsonResponse;

        if (function.equals("getUsers"))
            getUsers(jsonResponse);
    }

    private void getUsers(JsonResponse jsonResponse)
    {
        jsonResponse = new JsonResponse<List<User>>();

        // Lets say I have a class called User
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<Users>();
        // get users and add to list

        jsonResponse.setResponseData(users); // Warning on this line
        jsonResponse.setSuccess(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not mix Raw Type with Parametrized type.** Don't use Raw Type at all.

Modify `getUsers()` method because you are always creating a new `JsonResponse` i.e you don't need to pass any object.

```
private JsonResponse<List<User>> getUsers(){
    JsonResponse<List<User>> jsonResponse = new JsonResponse<List<User>>();

    // Lets say I have a class called User
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<Users>();
    // get users and add to list

    jsonResponse.setResponseData(users); // No warning on this line
    jsonResponse.setSuccess(true);
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

---

Please confirm. Most probably you have defined it as

```
public void setResponseData(Object value){...}
```

Replace it with below one

```
public void setResponseData(T value){...}
```

Comment: I have implemented it as setResponseData(T value)

Comment: The problem is here `JsonResponse<?> jsonResponse;`. I have updated it my post.

Comment: The reason for JsonResponse<?> jsonResponse is that the type T depends on the function parameter passed to the Servlet.

Comment: What are types that are passed?

Comment: have a look at my updated post for method `getUsers()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `JsonResponse` as a generic

```
private void getUsers(JsonResponse jsonResponse)
```

change it to

```
private void getUsers(JsonResponse<List<User>> jsonResponse)
```

Java always warn about using generics and for more information look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) question on SO.

Comment: Yes, at least the warning is gone now. But now I get compile error on getUsers(jsonResponse): The method getUsers(JsonResponse<JSONObject>) in the type AjaxJson is not applicable for the arguments (JsonResponse<capture#2-of ?>)